# expose internal dns kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am thinking of using K8S namespace for looking up services - using a git hash as the namespace for each version of a server, etc.

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/namespaces/#understanding-namespaces-and-dns

if you read the above it says internally the dns lookup uses a form:

```
<service-name>.<namespace-name>.svc.cluster.local
```

my question is - is there a way to expose the internal dns externally somehow? And specifically I am wondering if there is a way to provide the dns name instead of it being auto-created.

Comment: You probably want something like calico https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.7/getting-started/kubernetes/

Comment: and maybe this for ingress into the cluster https://docs.projectcalico.org/v3.5/usage/external-connectivity

Comment: It would help to understand where / how you are running Kubernetes. This would typically be handled with a combination of Ingress and LoadBalancer type Service.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to expose kube-dns service for queries outside cluster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449121/how-to-expose-kube-dns-service-for-queries-outside-cluster)

Comment: I think the answer to similar question on Stack Overflow was given already here:


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37449121/how-to-expose-kube-dns-service-for-queries-outside-cluster

Comment: This may help you to expose your service to outside the cluster [Using a Service to Expose Your App](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/)